# Declaring variable inside string

Tags: php, string

I have this kind of string.

```
'"asdfasdf","123456", this is a message. OK'
```

What i want to do is declare variables according to the first, second quotation and the rest of the message until the OK... 
(note: the length of the string inside the `''` is not consistent)

```
$First = "asdfasdf"
$Second = "123456"
$Message = "this is a message"
```

is this even possible?
is there something like `" "$First","$Second", "$Message" OK "` kind of way?
TIA.

Comment: there are several ways to achieve this, for example regular expressions

Comment: @Lashane can you please give me a link to learn your example. i keep finding rubbish in google. thanks.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regular expressions, like this:

**Code**

```
$raw = '"asdfasdf","123456", this is a message. OK'; // this is your raw text
preg_match('/^"(?P<first>[^"]+)","(?P<second>[^"]+)",\s+(?P<message>.+?) OK/', $raw, $matches); // this looks for the pattern you defined and stores the matches in $matches
print_r($matches); // this just dumps out the array of matching substrings
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => "asdfasdf","123456", this is a message. OK
    [first] => asdfasdf
    [1] => asdfasdf
    [second] => 123456
    [2] => 123456
    [message] => this is a message.
    [3] => this is a message.
)
```

You can access the individual substrings as, for example, `$matches['first']`, `$matches['second']`, or `$matches['message']`.

[**PHP Demo**](http://ideone.com/PFWnVY)

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/qI3eL0/1)

Comment: Thank you very much this is pretty much what i needed since the format is the same.

Comment: Sir, Can you help me please? I'm getting error with this one.I want to get the number,date,time,and message. I read the response from gsm modem using "fread" and I store it which result to $response='+CMGR: "REC READ","+639178397864",,"11/11/13,21:04:38+32"Hello WOrldOK'

Comment: This is a little trickier. You can try changing `\s+` above to `\s*` and seeing if that does what you want. If not, please post this as a new question using the [**Ask Question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. You can link to this question to provide context.

Answer (score 2):

Is this a CSV file ?
Doesn't seem to, but if it was you should check out the csv functions of php, specifically [str_getcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php).

If not, you should just do an explode by , or ", or any combination you think would be most accurate, and then go through each array item.

```
$string = '"asdfasdf","123456","this is a message. OK"';
$temp = explode('","',$string);
$array = array();
foreach($temp as $key=>$value){
//do stuff with $value and $key
}
```

Comment: instead of foreach-ing $temp, you can use `list`, may be a little faster if you only want to define some variables.

Comment: I'm thinking this might encounter a problem, for when the message will contain the symbol ",". Thanks this gave me an idea.